# Repeating Annotations on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make an annotation processor for my android projects.

My annotations are simply like this

```
@Author(name = "Jane Doe")
@Author(name = "John Smith")
class MyClass { ... }
```

But [Repeating Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html) are supported as of the  Java SE 8 Release and also android supports JDK 7 since API 19.

So Is there any way to use repeating annotations on android?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

As @Saeed stated, this is now possible on Android N

---

Unfortunately you can't. The only option I can think of would be to use something like:

```
@Author({ "Jane Doe", "John Smith"})
class MyClass { ... }
```

Or use other language highly compatible with android like Kotlin, which allows you to define `@Repeatable` annotations as you can see [on the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html)